# Flask render_template error: TemplateNotFound when using Docker Swarm/Stack

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Currently we use Docker Compose to start up services but we need secrets to secure passwords and the like, therefore the use of Docker Swarm & secrets is required.

Everything works perfectly with Compose but when we switch to Swarm a templating issue appears when loading the UI.

docker-compose.yml stripped down for simplicity

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgresql:
        image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:12.11.0
        volumes:
            - 'postgresql_data:/bitnami/postgresql'
        environment:
            #- ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
            - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=user
            - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=user
            - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/path/to/docker/secret
        secrets:
            - secret

    keycloak:
        image: docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:16.1.1
        depends_on:
            - postgresql
        environment:
            - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER=user
            - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD_FILE=/path/to/docker/secret
            - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT=5432
            - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST=postgresql
            - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME=user
            - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER=user
            - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE=/path/to/docker/secret
            - KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT=8083
            - KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT=8443
            - KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_TLS=true
            - KEYCLOAK_TLS_KEYSTORE_FILE=/path/to/keystore.jks
            - KEYCLOAK_TLS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_FILE=/path/to/docker/secret
            - KEYCLOAK_TLS_TRUSTSTORE_FILE=/path/to/truststore.jks
            - KEYCLOAK_TLS_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_FILE=/path/to/docker/secret
        volumes:
            - ".path/to/keycloak.jks:/opt/bitnami/keycloak/certs/keystore.jks"
            - ".path/to/keycloak.jks:/opt/bitnami/keycloak/certs/truststore.jks"
        networks:
            default:
                aliases:
                    - keycloak.host.net
                ports:
                    - 8083:8083
                    - 8443:8443
                secrets:
                    - secret

    ui:
        image: <image from AWS ECR>
        labels:
            COMPOSE_PATH: ${PWD}
        depends_on:
            - keycloak
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        restart: always
        environment:
            - HOSTNAME=ui
            - NAME=UI
            - PORT=8000
            - REGISTER_WITH_KEYCLOAK=True
            - ENVIRONMENT=prod
            - CONSUL_URL=http://consul-server-bootstrap:8500
            - MONGO_URI=mongodb://user:password@mongodb:27017/db
            - QUEUE_HOSTNAME=queue
```

UI code from config.py

```
# Landing page
@app.route("/")
    def index():
    try:
        current_app.logger.info(f"public/index.html page being displayed")
        return Response(render_template("public/index.html"), mimetype="text/html")
    except exception_with_data as ex:
        return ex.repr_as_dict(), 400
```

The error

```
2022-07-26T08:21:03.252452 Thread-83  UI  app ERROR Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ui/main/config.py", line 209, in index
return Response(render_template("public/index.html"), mimetype="text/html")
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 148, in render_template
ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1068, in get_or_select_template
return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 997, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 125, in load
source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 59, in get_source
return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 95, in _get_source_fast
raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: public/index.html
```

Code tree

```
ui
    /main
        app.py
        config.py
    /templates
        /admin
            <all admin html pages>
        /public
            index.html
            <all other public html pages>
```

All the files are in the correct location in the docker container.

The only difference between the yml files is the one for swarm has secrets.

`docker-compose up -d` works as expected and the UI pages render but when 
`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-swarm.yml name` is ran, the UI pages do not render.

The pages that do not use render_template (debugging pages) work fine and the UI registers with consul as expected.

Any help is appreciated!

Versions:

- Flask==2.0.1
- Werkzeug==2.0.1
- Jinja2==3.0.1
- itsdangerous==2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was because the `HOSTNAME` and `NAME` environment varibles in the `ui` section of the `docker-compose.yml`.

The wider back end system needed these to match.